# How can i take multiple string input in c?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I am trying to learn string in c. I have written this program. I want this program will terminate for a particular word (press ENTER after typing the word). Its Compile well but after given input when I pressing enter it shows me this message: **test.exe has stopped working.** **Here "test" is the name of my program.**
Please help me to understand this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j;

        char *str[10];
        for(i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            //gets(str[i]);
            scanf("%s",str[i]);
            if(str[i]=="man") break;
        }


        for(j=0; j<10; j++)
        {
            printf("%s\n",str[j]);
        }   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Two major bugs: `str` is uninitialised and you can't use `==` to compare strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For comparing strings in C, you can use `strcmp` function. For example:

```
if(strcmp(str[i],"man") == 0){
    # write your code here
}
```

And for initialization, do as follows.

```
char *str[10];
for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    str[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);
}
```

You can also do as following.

```
char str[10][1024];
for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    scanf("%s", str[i]);
}
```

**Alternative**: If you want to declare `str` as `char **str`, you can follow the following approach.

```
char **str = malloc(10*sizeof(char*));
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    str[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024); // buffer for 1024 chars
}
```

Comment: Note that it is [redundant and potentially dangerous to cast the result of malloc and friends in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/253056).

Comment: Thanks for your help brother